# Velocity is to speed as acceleration is to ________?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, terminology, vectors, velocity

Vectors give both magnitude and direction, whereas scalars can be thought of as magnitude without direction. So, velocity is a vector since it is speed with direction. Similarly, what is the scalar analog of acceleration?

Velocity is to speed as acceleration is to ______. If there is nothing to fill that blank, is there a reason why velocity is so special?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a scalar acceleration?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/477427/is-there-a-scalar-acceleration), [What does the magnitude of the acceleration mean?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/98420/84967), [Terminology for time derivative of speed (not velocity)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/494923/84967).

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Definitely a duplicate of [Is there a scalar acceleration?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/477427/).

Comment: "adjective: *scalar* : (of a quantity) having only magnitude, not direction" .... *a scalar quantity*. Alternate title for searchability: *What is acceleration without a direction?*

Comment: It is more accurate to construe scalars as having numerical values but no direction. A scalar _can_ be negative, in which case its "magnitude" (which technically equals its absolute value) differs from its numerical value.   (A vector, OTOH, is certainly well-characterised by its magnitude & direction.)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In English, it seems that:

- **Position** is a vector. **Distance/length** is a name of its magnitude.
- **Velocity** is a vector. **Speed** is a name of its magnitude.
- **Acceleration** is a name of a vector *and* its magnitude.
- **Force** is a name of a vector *and* its magnitude.
- **Momentum** is a name of a vector *and* its magnitude.
- ...

Velocity/speed as well as position/length seem to be exceptions. The general trend is to not have different names for the scalar-forms of vectors.

In fact, I asked [why this is the case on the History of Science and Math SE site](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/10984/why-are-speed-and-velocity-not-given-the-same-name) a few months ago.

The answer told me that Gibbs and Wilson formally defined the difference between speed/velocity in technical English in 1901 in their book *Vector Analysis*:

> Velocity is a vector quantity. Its direction is the direction of the tangent of the curve described by the particle. The term speed is used frequently to denote merely the scalar value of the velocity. This convention will be followed here.

Since then, others continued this trend and it eventually got settled. Before then, the distinction was less clear.

In other languages, there is not necessarily such a distinction. It is consensus in English, Spanish, my mother-tongue Danish and others, but not in Russian, German etc.

Comment: I think part of the reason is that in common parlance, 'speed' and 'velocity' only refer to the scalar.  If I'm driving around a radius curve at a constant speed, my velocity is changing (in technical language) but in the vernacular, I'm driving at a constant velocity.

Comment: Sometimes the magnitude of the force vector is called "load", or "loading".

Comment: Also also, the change in acceleration over time (the third order derivative of position) is "[Jerk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerk_(physics))." Snap (or [Jounce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jounce), Crackle, and [Pop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pop_(physics)) are the fourth, fifth, and six respectively.

Comment: @JimmyJames Disagree completely. I have yet to hear anyone describe "driving at a constant velocity" outside of a technical context. Velocity IS a technical term.

Comment: @Aron I do hear velocity used as a scalar.  For example, a "high velocity projectile."  I think usually "velocity" means a vector quantity, but it doesn't seem to be universal.  Its certainly better than other terms in that regard.

Comment: @CortAmmon-ReinstateMonica That example is fair. Also, I have heard of acceleration used in the scalar sense too, for example when talking about the capabilities of a performance vehicle.

Comment: In natural language, velocity does not necessarily imply a vector (even after the distinction that Gibbs made). [Speed](www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/speed) and [velocity](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/velocity) are actually still synonyms in more than one meaning. Only scientific use (mechanics branch of physics) makes this distinction, possibly because it was easier to say speed instead of magnitude of velocity all the time.

Comment: In other words, the OP is looking at this the wrong way around.  It's not that "velocity" is the exception in being a vector, but that "speed" is the exception being a magnitude and *not* a vector.

Comment: @Aron Lookup "high-velocity fan" for an [example](https://www.hunker.com/13408380/the-difference-between-a-high-capacity-fan-a-high-velocity-fan).  Here's an example from an article titled ["The Physics of speeding cars"](https://www.science.org.au/curious/technology-future/physics-speeding-cars) where the terms are used more or less interchangeably: "If the car's initial speed was 70 kilometres/hour, the impact velocity would be 45 kilometres/hour, more than fast enough to kill."

Comment: I'm surprised by your comment on Spanish, because I'm under the impression that *velocidad* is the primary word for *speed* and it's only for variety that people use synonyms (*rapidez* being the one that comes to mind).

Comment: @PeterTaylor Yes, there are various opinions on this, for instance on the [Spanish SE site](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/13158/do-rapidez-and-velocidad-have-similar-technical-meanings-as-speed-and-vel), where this question has been asked. I have asked a few Spanish-native engineering colleagues who confirmed that they basically don't have/use the distinction at all, not even technically - and that the term *rapidez* is equivalent to something like *rapidness* in English, which I wouldn't use in technical English anyways.

Answer (score 4):

g-force is typically used to express the magnitude only, but the words are generally used interchangeably; laymen typically referring to the magnitude only.

Comment: This is very specific to comparisons made with the force of gravity, but it does normally refer just to a scalar.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a word, coin it, define it in your writing and use it consistently. I would use *hastening* or *quickening*. For instance, an object going around in a circle at constant speed (thus angular velocity) isn't quickening, though it is constantly accelerating.

Comment: My actual use case was for function and variable names in python code. So I guess prefixing with ‘vector_...’ and ‘scalar_...’.

Answer (score 0):

Impulse required to start or stop something moving.  Of course, there's mass involved, so you might want to take Impulse/mass

Answer (score 0):

**Speed-Up / Sped-Up**

From Google's definition:

> noun
>   an increase in speed, especially in a person's or machine's rate of working.

Some examples:

1. I sped-up (accelerated) to catch my friends in front of me.
2. Bobby will need to speed-up (accelerate) to overtake the race leader.
3. The rocket fired its booster engines and sped-up (accelerated) to 10 km/s

Comment: We do not say that since the magnitude of the train's velocity is 30m/s, the train speeds at 30m/s, so I don't think this is analogous to speed.