# How is called the magnitude of acceleration?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, terminology, vectors

According to [wikipedia page of velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity):

> The scalar absolute value (magnitude) of **velocity** is called **speed**

and according to [wikipedia page of acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceleration):

> Accelerations are vector quantities (in that they have magnitude and direction)

thus I am wondering,
**How is called the magnitude of acceleration?**

Comment: Not a native speaker, but I'm pretty sure that it's just "acceleration".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Velocity is to speed as acceleration is to \_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/517636/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no separate word to distinguish the [vector of acceleration](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/acca.html) from its magnitude.

The same is true with the word *force*, which is also both a vector and often described by the same word when talking of its magnitude.

[Velocity](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/vel2.html) and speed seem to be the exception,  probably because  speed is an everyday term, " speed of going from town A to town B" implies curving roads and changing vectors.